# Simple example of how to use a class based view and django-filter?

Tags: django-views, django-class-based-views, django-filter

The example in the documentation, https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html,  is I think for a function based view.  I am currently researching how to do this with a class based view.

```py
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit more digging and I have managed to answer it. I have used the code from here https://github.com/rasca/django-enhanced-cbv.

I added the contents of `list.py` into my main app as `main_app/filter_mixin.py`

Then in the app I was adding a search to the list view I added the file `filter.py` like this (identical to documentation)

```
from django_filters import FilterSet
from .models import Contact


class ContactFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name_first', 'name_last']
```

Now the `view.py` becomes:

```
from vanilla import ListView

from .filter import ContactFilter
from galleria.filter_mixin import ListFilteredMixin


class ContactList(ListFilteredMixin, ListView):
    filter_set = ContactFilter
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with just overwriting the queryset to allow filtering and context to embed the filters in the template.

```py
class ObjFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Obj
        fields = ["field1", "field2"]


class ObjView(ListView):
    template_name = "template.html"
    model = Obj
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ["-id"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        filter = ObjFilter(self.request.GET, queryset)
        return filter.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filter = ObjFilter(self.request.GET, queryset)
        context["filter"] = filter
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link [Viewing subsets of objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects)

You can use something like this is your `views.py`

```
class modelListView(someGenericView):
        queryset = modelName.object.filter(myFilter)
```